# Can I require jsx files in node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx

I have a script that does some analysis on my source files and a part of that analysis is to `require` the file. Some of the files are in JSX format however and node does not understand this by default.

Is it possible to make it so that a file that looks like this:

```
function MyModule () {
  return <div>hello</div>
}

module.exports = MyModule
```

is possible to require through `require('./my-module')`?

Comment: You could add a custom oader (eg: babel) for your application, React supports server-side rendering too.

Comment: I am familiar with babel but not custom loaders. Do you have a link to documentation of those?

Comment: Have a look at [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register) it will basically add functionality to the standard node require allowing you to load custom filetypes. You will then need [babel-preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) to load jsx files.

Answer (score 2):

Use JSX as a template engine in Node

**NPM Package :** https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-node

To be able to simply require .jsx files, you need to tell Node what to do with them. Running the following code makes you able to require('./SomeFile.jsx'):

```
require('jsx-node').install({
  replace: {
    preact: 'jsx-node',
  }
});
```

**Warning:**

This module is still in a very early phase. Any production use should be approached with caution.

For more Detail visit Link.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I decided to go with babel-register as recommended in the comment above though. It seems to be the more common and flexible way to go.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson If possible, it would be useful to share your babel-register solution here for others :)